# Not able to insert the data in input field of form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form, there is a button (+sign)on the form which appends a row to insert the value .In my form i am able to enter the value on the first row both fields( `stationerytype` and `stationeryqty`). But once I append  a new row by clicking plus button I am not able to insert any value  on `staionerytype` field of second row while I'm able to insert the value in the `stationeryqty` field of second row.

[image]

My code is:

```
<table   class="table table-bordered" id="tb" >
<tr class="tr-header">

<th class= "col-md-1" align="centre">Sl.No.</th>
<th class= "col-md-6" align="centre">STATIONARY TYPE</th>
<th class= "col-md-4" align="centre">STATIONARY QUANTITY</th>
<th class= "col-md-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Stationery"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>

</tr>
<tr>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)
{   
?>

<td><input type="text" style="text-decoration: none" name="slno" value= "<?php echo $i; ?>"  ></td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-decoration: none" name="stationerytype"  ></td>
<td><input type="number" name="stationeryqtyrecd" id="stationeryqtyrecd" min="0"></td>

<td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
</tr>
<?php  }?>
</table>

<button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-info"  align="middle" >ADD </button>   

<script>
var max = 4;
var count = 1;
$(function(){
    $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
            if(count <= max ){
              var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
              data.find("input").val('');
              debugger;
              data.find("input")[0].value=++count;
            }else{
             alert("Sorry!! Can't add more than five samples at a time !!");
           }
              
     });
     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>1) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");

     var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        if(trIndex>1) {
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
         count--;
         
         // get all the rows in table except header.
         $('#tb tr:not(.tr-header)').each(function(){
         $(this).find('td:first-child input').val(this.rowIndex);
         })
           }
      });
}); 
 
</script>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Your code is working i am not finding any such behaviour . Only there was syntax error you have not close `else {..` part under `.remove` event .Also , this `<?php for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++){   ?>` should be above  `<tr>` tag not inside.

Comment: @Swati It is not working suppose if i am changing the value of second row stationerytype  it will change the value of row 1 stationerytype and second row stationery type value will be blank

Comment: can you create demo code ?

Comment: @Swati I am sory to say that inthe given code the input method is simple.BUt in my actual code I am using Option  attribute  Which fetches the value from a table  I that case I am not able to insert value  on second line  sationerytype  field .if i click on the second row and select any value iot changes the value of first line .